# How to execute something in current shell

Tags: shell, exec, eval

I want to create a bash script or something similar that I can execute in the current shell:

```
 echo '#!/bin/bash 
  export foo="bar" ' > zoom.sh
```

but if I want to run this script in the current process:

```
exec ./zoom.sh
```

then my terminal will just exit "process completed", even if I use `set +e`, it still exits.

There's `source` and `eval` which will run stuff in the current shell, so maybe eval is my best bet?  A bash function will work - but I have to rely on the user to `source` it in the first place.

Comment: You use `source` or `.`. `eval` is for strings.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Depending on the real goal, any of a number of approaches might be best.

Comment: just trying to change the current shell - like alter the PATH using `export PATH=` that kind of thing.

Comment: @AlexanderMills This is _exactly_ what `source` is for.

Answer (score 2):

From manual, looks like exec will not create new process it just replace the current shell, so after execution it will terminate the session too.

> `exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments]]`:
>   If command is specified,
>   it replaces the shell.  No new process is created.  The arguments
>   become the arguments to command.  If the -l option is supplied, the
>   shell places a dash at the beginning of the zeroth argument passed to
>   command.  This is what login(1) does.  The `-c` option causes
>   command to be executed with an empty environment. If  `-a` is 
>   supplied, the shell passes name as the zeroth argument to the executed
>   command.  If command cannot be executed for some reason, a
>   non-interactive shell exits, unless the shell option `execfail` is
>   enabled, in which case it returns failure.  An interactive shell
>   returns failure if the file cannot be executed.  If command is not 
>   specified,  any redirections take effect in the current shell, and the
>   return status is 0.  If there is a redirection error, the return
>   status is 1.

```
$ cat zoom.sh
#!/bin/bash
export foo="bar"
echo $?
$ exec ./zoom.sh
0
Connection to localhost closed
```